# XCode 13.3 Pod Install Removes Path To Flutter Module

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-module

we are using Flutter as a Module embedded in our project, and we have some problems.
When upgraded to xcode 13.3 , we run into an issue :

Running pod install in the iOS project removes the path to the flutter module like this:
[image]

When discarding these lines the project runs and all good, but when including those changes i get a crash:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/App.framework/App
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/SomeRandomGeneratedNumber/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: image not found

The question is :
Was there a change for the flutter module configuration so the pod install removes the path to the flutter module? how is it connected to xcode13.3 and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround :

Install Cocoapods using HomeBrew and not Gem.

See continuation here :

[Install Cocoapods : Brew vs Regular installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74508234/install-cocoapods-brew-vs-regular-installation?noredirect=1#comment131527282_74508234)