# Install Cocoapods : Brew vs Regular installation

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, homebrew

Background :

We have an app that embeds Flutter as module in our iOS project. When i install cocoapods using the original option from cocoa like this :

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then run `pod install` in my iOS project, i get the Flutter module thrown out of project file, like mentioned in this issue :

[XCode 13.3 Pod Install Removes Path To Flutter Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72302377/xcode-13-3-pod-install-removes-path-to-flutter-module)

Although, i found a workaround : i installed cocoapods using Homebrew and it works perfectly.

My question here is: What is the key difference, or what are the differences between the original website installation of cocoapods and the homebrew one?

NOTE: The same behavior is noticed for apple silicon and intel chips.

Comment: Isn't this basically a repetition of your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72302377/xcode-13-3-pod-install-removes-path-to-flutter-module ?

Comment: It might seem as such, but here i ask specifically about the difference between HomeBrew installation of cocoapods and the Gem one

Comment: But don't you think that, having solved the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72302377/xcode-13-3-pod-install-removes-path-to-flutter-module, you should take it down? My advice would be, incorporate it into this one and delete it.

Comment: The issue is resolved but the mystery remains, although they are related but it's not the same question. The other question that you mentioned can in fact be closed and i will post an answer to it and accept it. maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: Cool, thanks for helping to keep SO organized and helpful.

Comment: Done, maybe you can give your insight on the matter?